# R Markdown affiliation doesn't appear in the pdf-document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to add the affiliation and the e-mail adress in a pdf-article in r-markdown. But with my code the affiliation and the e-mail adress doesn't appear.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"

date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
keywords: "keywords"

author:
  -name: My Name
  affiliation: University of somewhere
  email: test@e-mail.com

output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_cap: yes
    keep_tex: yes
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: "apalike"
link-citations: true
documentclass: article
capsize: normalsize
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
spacing: doublespacing
footerdate: yes
abstract: 'Insert abstract here'
---
```

[image]

Here is the Output with the help of the BiocManager-package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

- Space between "-" and "name" ?
- Did you import BiocStyle 2.11.0 ?

src : https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/BiocStyle/inst/doc/AuthoringRmdVignettes.html

It's only a supposition, hope it'll do the job !

Comment: I inserted the space between "-" and "name" but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to remove it then, when i put it in a Yaml linter, it show an error

Answer (score 0):

The regular `pdf_document` output format doesn't support `affiliation` etc.  You need to output to `BiocStyle::pdf_document`.  You also have the formatting for the `author` specification wrong, which causes troubles.

```
---
title: "title"
subtitle: "subtitle"

date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
keywords: "keywords"

author:
  - name: My Name
    affiliation: University of somewhere
    email: test@e-mail.com

output:
  BiocStyle::pdf_document:
    fig_cap: yes
    keep_tex: yes
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: "apalike"
link-citations: true
documentclass: article
capsize: normalsize
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
spacing: doublespacing
footerdate: yes
abstract: 'Insert abstract here'
---
```

To install `BiocStyle` if you haven't already got it, you first need to install `BiocManager` in the regular way, then use it to install `BiocStyle`:

```
install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("BiocStyle")
```

Comment: These code works, but it gives me an output in a totally different format. I've put a screenshot of it into my question.

Comment: Yes, that's the Bioconductor style.  If you want something like the `pdf_document` style but with the additional fields, you're going to need to customize the Pandoc template yourself.  The standard one is one of the files in `system.file("rmd/latex", package = "rmarkdown")` (probably `default-1.17.0.2.tex`, but you may have a different version).  `BiocStyle` edits this file to add support for affiliations and to change the default style using its internal function `BiocStyle:::create_latex_template`.  It should be possible to figure out what its doing and do it yourself.